# Download a PDF on firefox from a lightbox in Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, firefox, lightbox

Good morning,

I've been trying to download a PDF from a website from selenium, but on a recent change on the site now the PDF is displayed on a lightbox, in an Iframe, I thought about getting the url but it gets it via POST method so I can't find the precise URL of the pdf file I want to download in the source code, I also tryed to click on the button to download the pdf but it doens't seem able to find it.

Code trial:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_framePDF"]')) 
btnDownload = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download"]') 
btnDownload.click()
```

Comment: How are you selecting the button? CSS, Xpath, name, id...? Please share your HTML and your script.

Comment: have you tried switching to the Iframe and then downloading?

Comment: Please  show us your code. Which `pdf` are you trying to download?